# Convergence of dynamical system to stable equilibrium $(xy-1)^2$ to set $\{xy = 1\}$.

Tags: dynamical-systems, lyapunov-functions

Consider the following dynamical system:

$\dot{x} = -(xy-1)y$ and $\dot{y} = -(xy-1)x.$

I would like to show that $x,y$ converge to set $xy = 1.$

1. Using Lyapunov function $V = (xy-1)^2,$ we can show that $\dot{V} = -(xy-1)^2(x^2+y^2)\le 0$ with equality only when $S = \{x=y=0 or \{xy = 1\}\}.$ Hence by [Lasalle invariance principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaSalle%27s_invariance_principle) we can show that it asymptotically converges to $S.$
2. Consider the Lyapunov function $V = x^2 + y^2,$ and set $U = \{x\ge 0,y\ge 0\}.$ We can show that $\dot{V} = -2xy(xy-1)$ is positive is a neighborhood around $(0,0)$ in set $U$. Hence using [Chetaev instability theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chetaev_instability_theorem) we can argue that $(0,0)$ is an unstable equilibrium point.

My question is, does argument 1) and 2) show that $xy=1$ is asymptotically stable?

EDIT --

To prove - For almost all initializations in a bounded set $x<R,y<R, R<\infty$ the set $S = \{xy=1\}$ is asymptotically stable, i.e. the set of initializations that lead to point $\{x=y=0\}$ is of measure zero. I am hoping to show this using Lyapunov analysis, and maybe not apply Stable Manifold Theorem.

Comment: No need for fancy theorems. Your vector field is a scalar multiple of $(x,y)$, so the phase portrait will look like for a star node, $(\dot x, \dot y) = (x,y)$, except that the direction of the trajectories will depend on the sign of $xy-1$, i.e., on which side of the curve $xy=1$ that you're on.

Comment: Thanks, I understand where you are coming from. I was hoping to use the theorems in this case so that I can extend it to 'similar' dynamical theorems in higher dimensions

Comment: @HansLundmark : The vector field is a multiple of $(y,x)$, which results in hyperbolic curves, that is, $(0,0)$ being a saddle point.

Comment: @LutzLehmann: Yes, you're right. I misread the ODEs.

Comment: @user2542950: I see, but it's not quite clear to me what you want to accomplish. By applying LaSalle correctly, I think it should be possible already in step (1) to show that the set $xy=1$ is asymptotically stable. So what additional information are you seeking in step (2)? Are you looking for some global statement? That seems impossible, since in your example solutions starting on the line $y=-x$ will converge to the origin (along that line), not to the set $xy=1$.

Comment: sorry, I should have been more clear. I am looking to show that for `almost all' initializations the ODEs converge to the set $xy=1$, i.e. the set of initializations that lead to $x=y=0$ is measure zero, either globally or in a bounded set. In my understanding Chetaev instability is just saying that $x=y=0$ is unstable, but can we conclude that the set of initializations that lead to $x=y=0$ is of measure zero at least in the local region of $x=y=0$ from Chetaev. I have put an edit to the questions as well.

Answer (score 0):

The proof is exactly the same as yours (the first approach), with a little analysis added.

Let $s = x y - 1$ and $s = 0$ be the equilibrium.

Taking the time derivative of $s$ yields

$$ \begin{align*} 
 \dot{s} &= x \dot{y} + \dot{x} y \\ 
 \dot{s} &= - x \left[\left(x y - 1\right) x\right] - \left[\left(x y - 1\right) y\right] y \\
 \dot{s} &= - s x^{2} - s y^{2} \\
 \dot{s} &= - s \left(x^{2} + y^{2}\right) \\
\end{align*} $$

The result shows that $s$ will converge to $0$ so long as $x^{2} + y^{2} > 0$. This also implies we cannot have $x = 0 \land y = 0$. Continue with the Lyapunov stability proof, we have the candidate function

$$ V(s) = \frac{1}{2} s^{2} .$$

Taking the time derivative of $V$ yields

$$ \begin{align*} 
 \dot{V}(s) &= s \dot{s} \\
 \dot{V}(s) &= s \left[- s \left(x^{2} + y^{2}\right)\right] \\
 \dot{V}(s) &= - \left(x^{2} + y^{2}\right) s^{2} < 0 \quad \forall \; s \neq 0 \land x \neq 0 \land y \neq 0 \\
 \dot{V}(s) &= - 2 \left(x^{2} + y^{2}\right) V .\\
\end{align*} $$

The stream plot looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, I am seeking some clarity in your proof. Can you please elaborate how showing that $V = 0.5 s^2 , \dot{V} = -2(x^2 +y^2)V<0$ concludes that the set $x=y=0$ is not an asymptotically stable point? As in, $V$ is only negative when $x^2+y^2>0,$ how does this imply that $x,y$ both cannot be zero in the entire trajectory?

Comment: Given $\dot{s} = - k s$ and assuming that $k > 0$ is a constant, the solution $s(t) = s_{0} e^{- k t}$ is exponentially convergent from rest $s_{0}$ to the equilibrium $s = 0$. If $k = 0$, then $\dot{s} = 0$ (*rate of change is zero*) and the solution $s(t)$ is a constant. For $k = x^{2} + y^{2} = 0$, only both $x = 0 \land y = 0$ satisfy the condition. Also, if both $x = 0 \land y = 0$, then $s = x y - 1 \neq 0$, which is not a known stable equilibrium according to $\dot{s} = - \left(x^{2} + y^{2}\right) s$. The same argument may be applied to $\dot{V} = - 2 \left(x^{2} + y^{2}\right) V$.

Comment: I guess it is unclear to me that we can show exponential stability of s when k may become 0 during the trajectory. How do you handle the case that the initialization is on y=-x like @hanlu09 pointed out?